# Extract certain values from multiple lines from a txt file

Tags: python, string, parsing, split

Similar questions have been asked and answered before, but I'd like to know why my code doesn't yield the correct output.

There are a couple of lines in my txt file that look like this: `X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.xxxx`

The 0.xxxx value varies. I need to slice that part out of each "X-DSPAM-Confidence:" line and calculate an average.

The txt file can be downloaded here: http://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox-short.txt

My code is as follows:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
count = 0
current = 0
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") : continue   # Please do not change this line and develop the program based on it
    count = count + 1  # I think this would count how many lines that starts with X-DSPAM-Confidence:
    pos = line.find(':')    # This should find me the position for ":"
    number = line[pos+5:]   # I think this should slice the number out
    final = float(number) + current    # Then I float the number and add to the current running number
print("Average spam confidence: ", final/count)    # Finally, when the loop finishes with the file, print the average
```

Using the code above, I got the average 33.5925925926, but the correct answer should be 0.750718518519.

Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: You never reuse `final`, do `current= float(number) + current` and `current/count` at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you requested, with minimal but essential changes.

```
    fname = input("Enter file name: ")
    with open(fname, "r") as current_file: 
        # i can not stress enough the importance of the with method over 
        #open()/close()
            content = current_file.readlines()

    count = 0
    current = 0
    for line in content:
        if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"): continue
        count = count + 1  
        pos = line.find(':')    
        number = line[pos+2:]   # small error, it was not 5 but 2 instead
        current = float(number) + current
    print("Average spam confidence: ", current/count)
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for your code. I am actually taking an online lesson. I haven't learned that much yet. Is it possible that you change my code as little as possible to get the desired output?

Comment: @LeonC there it is the code. I hope it will suite your requests

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked! I've stuck with this for like 8 hours. I need to study your beginning part, with open() and content = current_file.readlines(). I haven't learned those yet.

Comment: May I know why it's pos+2? I had an easier exercise where I needed to slice the value out of the line "X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8475". In this exercise, I extracted position [23:29] and it worked. I started with X as position 0 and counted each letter and small space one by one.  I think there are 4 small empty spaces before the number 0.8475. But it seems by doing pos +2 the entire empty spaces are treated as 1.

Comment: Just found that pos+1, +2, +3 all worked. Starting from +4 there would be a problem

Comment: If you must use open(filename) remember to also use close(filename) when you are done with your program. If you want to learn something new the "with" method is what you need. Basically, it open the file by saying => with open(filename). Then, it create an alias that reference that file by saying => as current_file. As third step, it create a list of lines and stores them in the variable "content". In the end, even if you don't write anything, the script will automatically close the file as soon as the indentetion of "with" ends.

Comment: For the slicing problem: in python, lists and strings can be sliced by their index. Each list/string starts at index 0 and go up by one (this is the easy part). For the slicing part we have two things to consider: line.find(":") return the integer index where the script have found it. Then, since we want the numerical value, we need to skip one place, so it would be [pos+1:]. Now I don't know why it has worked with pos+2 but I assumed  that python, given the float .123 managed to create the float 0.123, but I am not too sure

Comment: Very clear. Thanks! For the pos+1 part, I did some experiment here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xsjqNAo_A-druJFsZsbcLILou8f77oku?usp=sharing
So yeah, it looks python is smart enough to ignore the spaces before a value and do math accordingly.